# Evaluation of line lintegral along the parabola $y=x^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Evaluation of $$\int_{C}xydx+(x+y)dy$$  aling the curve $y=x^2$ from $(-2,4)$ to $(1,1)$

What i try

Let $\vec{F}=\bigg<xy,x+y\bigg>$ and let $\vec{r}=\bigg<x,y\bigg>$

So we have to calculate $$\int_{C}\vec{F}\cdot \vec{dr}$$

Now let paramatrize the curve $y=x^2$

So we take $x=t$ and $y=t^2$. Then $-2\leq t\leq 1$

So $$\int^{1}_{-2}\vec{F(t)}\cdot \frac{d}{dt}\bigg<\vec{r(t)}\bigg>dt$$

$$\int^{1}_{-2}\bigg<t\cdot t^2,t+t^2\bigg>\cdot \bigg<1,2t\bigg>dt$$

$$\int^{1}_{-2}\bigg(t^3+2t(t+t^2\bigg)dt$$

Can please tell me is my process is right. If not Then How do i solve it. Help me please

Comment: Yes this looks correct to me.

Comment: Except there is a problem. $(1,2)$ is not on the parabola.

Comment: Thanks peter and Ninad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could also directly plug in the functions

$$\int_C xy\:dx + (x+y)\:dy = \int_{-2}^1 x^3\:dx + \int_4^0 -\sqrt{y}+y\:dy  + \int_0^1 \sqrt{y} + y \: dy= -\frac{21}{4}$$

with no extra parametrization work necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid method.

It may be useful to note that instead of taking dot products, one can just write
$$\int_C f(x) \, dx + g(x) \, dy = \int_a^b \left(f(x(t)) \frac{dx}{dt} + g(x(t)) \frac{dy}{dt} \right) \, dt$$
after parametrising $C$ with $t \in [a, b]$, which perhaps shortens the work a little (though it's essentially the same thing).